# etcd backup / snapshot in openshift 3.7

Tags: openshift, etcd

I am confused about the etcd backup / restore documentation of OpenShift 3.7: The [OpenShift Container Platform 37 Admin Guide](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/admin_guide/backup_restore.html#etcd-backup) 
 tells us to use `etcdctl backup`. This looks like a etcd version 2 command to me - I'm new to etcd so I'm please bear with me. The [etcd 3.2.9 recovery guide](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/3.2.9/op-guide/recovery.html) mentions only `etcdctl snapshot save`, no `etcdctl backup`. 
OpenShift 3.7 comes with etcd version: 3.2.9:

> Starting in OpenShift Container Platform 3.7, the use of the etcd3 v3
>   data model is required.

Shouldn't the OpenShift admins be using `etcdctl snapshot` then?

[OpenShift Container Platform 3.7 Release notes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/release_notes/ocp_3_7_release_notes.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is correct, in OpenShift 3.7 we go with API version 2 and `etcdctl backup`.
I was indeed confused about the etcd versions. In OpenShift 3.7, we have:

```
# etcdctl -v
etcdctl version: 3.2.9
API version: 2
```

and **data model** version v3.

Comment: Yes and I tried to capture this (general Kube-related) issue here: https://hackernoon.com/notes-on-moving-from-etcd2-to-etcd3-dedb26057b90

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is accurate - the version is showing API version: 2 because it is the default API without any other changes. You can simply specify ETCDCTL_API=3 to use the new API version which is much more helpful in OCP 3.7 onwards.

```
[~]# etcdctl  --version
etcdctl version: 3.2.9
API version: 2
[~]# ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl version
etcdctl version: 3.2.9
API version: 3.2
```

The documentation appears to be lacking on the RH side (attempt to do an ls with etcdctl API version 2 -- nothing will display despite the RH documentation indicating it will. It feels like this is due to the etcdctl API v2 not interacting with the v3 data model as far as I can tell).